# Linux mint - Wifi doesn't work

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, linux-mint

I am a beginner on linux. Someone just put linux mint in dual boot with windows 10 on my pc. The problem is that I can connect only by ethernet. I have intel dual bande wireless-ac 3168 so i follow this [link](https://techridez.com/blog/install-intel-dual-band-wireless-ac-3168-driver-linux/)

But it doesn't work. I put some screenshot :

[version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHR65.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you have a graphical desktop, there is a network icon in the systray, from which you can start Wifi networks. Also, on desktop Linuxen, networks are managed through the NetworkManager framework, so you should have an `nmcli` utility installed (this is the command-line version of the systray icon). Try for instance `nmcli device` to show which devices are seen and controlled by NetworkManager.

Comment: With the nmcli device i have : enpls0f1 Ethernet unavailable --    and  lo  loopback  unmanaged  --

Answer (score 0):

It's working now ! 
I just upgrade kernel from 4.4 to 4.8 with the update manager and now i can see the available wireless network and connect to them